# How Script Do I Do I Even Java?

Tags: javascript, html, input, counter, notepad

I want to make a website that tracks the amount of cigarettes you smoke in a day. 
The overall goal is to help smokers cut back by reaching set goals for themselves.
The first important function is the number of cigarettes that are intended to be smoked that day. The second is a clicker that keeps track of the amount of cigarettes smoked that day.

Here's what I have:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>SMOKERS TOOL</title>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Daily goal</h3>

<input type="number" id="myNumber" value="1">

<p>This is how many smokes you're having today</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">SUBMIT</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

}
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var clicks = 0;
    function onClick() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
    </script>
    <button type="button" style="height:200px;width:200px" onClick="onClick()">HIT ME EVERY TIME YOU SMOKE</button>
    <p>THIS IS HOW MUCH YOU'VE SMOKED TODAY: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>

</body>


</html>
```

I'm really new to this sort of thing and I have a lot of questions that
I'm not quite sure how to ask yet but I was wondering how to
make some text appear like "You went over the goal!" when the Number of cigarettes smoked goes over the daily goal. Let me know if you guys have any recommendations as well. The SUBMIT text  shows up as a button when 
I save it as an html file. I'm doing everything with notepad.

Comment: "How do I even javascript?" great title. I would recommend reading the help center for some advice and tips on how to ask good questions.

Comment: Thank you! I have read through some of the help centers advice and tips to get a better understanding of what I should ask and I have corrected my title to make it more specific.

Comment: Lol. Nice job. "How Script Do I Do I Even Java?" Are you even trying? That is not a good title. There is a reason my comment has 7 up votes.

Comment: Honestly I appreciate your honesty it's refreshing

Comment: Yep. Why don't you look into the help center to see why your question was put on hold. Reading that will help for future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <html>
  <head>
      <title>SMOKERS TOOL</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <h3>Daily goal</h3>

  <input type="number" id="myNumber" value="1">

  <p>This is how many smokes you're having today</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">SUBMIT</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>

      function myFunction() {
          var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

  }
  </script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
      var clicks = 0;
      var surpassedDailyGoal = false;

      function onClick() {
        var dailyGoal = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;


          clicks += 1;
          document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;

        if( clicks > dailyGoal && !surpassedDailyGoal ){
          surpassedDailyGoal = true;
          document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p>Stop smoking you chimney you...</p>');
        }
      };
      </script>
      <button type="button" style="height:200px;width:200px" onClick="onClick()">HIT ME EVERY TIME YOU SMOKE</button>
      <p>THIS IS HOW MUCH YOU'VE SMOKED TODAY: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>

  </body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The chimney thing was a nice touch.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering how to make some text appear like "You went over the
>   goal!" when the Number of cigarettes smoked goes over the daily goal.

You just need to check if `clicks` is greater than your goal number when you execute your `onClick` function.

```
var goal = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
if (clicks > goal) {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You went over your goal!";
   //or...
   alert("You went over your goal!");
}
```

Comment: Very helpful. I have a lot to learn

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>SMOKERS TOOL</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>Daily goal</h3>

  <input type="number" id="myNumber" value="4">

  <p>This is how many smokes you're having today</p>

  <p id="demo"></p>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">SUBMIT</button>

  <button type="button" id='btn' onClick="onClick()">HIT ME EVERY TIME YOU SMOKE</button>
  <p id='disp'>THIS IS HOW MUCH YOU'VE SMOKED TODAY:
    <p id="clicks">0</p>
  </p>
</body>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
    clicks = -1;
    onClick();
  }

  var clicks = 0;

  function onClick() {

    clicks += 1;
    if (clicks <= document.getElementById("myNumber").value) {
      document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML = "THIS IS HOW MUCH YOU'VE SMOKED TODAY: ";
      document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = '';
      document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML = 'You have exceeded the limit of ' + (clicks - 1) + ' cigarettes. ';
    }
  };
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: I can't seem to get the top snippet to run as an html file without just appearing as text when I combine the two. Also I can't submit the number in the daily goal. Is it a different format when i'm using notepad and saving it as an html file than when you run the code snippet? Am I missing something?

Comment: @LarryMonnroe Have updated the snippet into a single html section. Just place the entire code in a .html file and open it in any browser. `Hit me everytime u smoke` to count the no of times u smoke, and to increase/ decrease change the daily goal and click on `Submit` button. On resetting the daily goal, the count gets reset. Please let me know in case of concerns.

Comment: Thanks! It's amazing all the different ways to skin a cat in code.

Comment: @LarryMonnroe Glad to have been of help! Feel free to upvote if you feel it was useful to you. :-) Happy StackOverflowing!

Comment: My reputations too low to change the display

Comment: I can now............